# Why is the MySQL Query slow although with index?

Tags: mysql, performance

The following Query takes about 9 seconds. That seems pretty slow to me. Any ideas why it is so slow?

```
mysql> explain SELECT ts, wert
->  FROM visu_werte_int v0_
-> WHERE v0_.wert_id = 163
->   AND v0_.ts <= '2016-01-25 23:00:00'
->   AND v0_.ts >= '2016-01-24 23:00:00';
```

[image: Explain result]

Comment: what are the indexes available into the table ? `show indexes from visu_werte_int`

Comment: Primary Key on ts and wert_id

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT ts, wert 
FROM visu_werte_int v0_ WHERE v0_.wert_id = 163 AND v0_.ts BETWEEN '2016-01-223:00:00' AND '2016-01-25 23:00:00';
```

if u have a problem create index on your column wert_id same this:

```
create index ix_visu_werte_int_search on visu_werte_int(wert_id,ts) using BTREE;
```

Comment: older version of mysql with myisam engine does not use index for date column when between is used.

Comment: index on wert_id for me if he has many results with unique ID.

Comment: An Index on the column wert_id doesn't help. I've just tried it. And the Mysql version is just thow months old.

Comment: @Markus try this `create index ix_visu_werte_int_search on visu_werte_int(wert_id,ts) using BTREE;`

Comment: Thanks rdn87 ... that helped: 0.0788 Seconds :)

Answer (score -1):

If you currently have `PRIMARY KEY(ts, wert_id)`, consider swapping the order -- it would make *this* query a lot faster.  However, it *may* hurt other queries.  So, let's see all your queries before deciding.

[Indexing cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)